# How to handle co-worker's leg shaking?

Tags: professionalism

A recently hired co-worker has the habit of almost constantly shaking their legs. My desk is located rather close to said co-worker, and the almost constant vibration is wearing on me. I have tried to separate my desk to minimize the effect, but to no avail.

I am considering politely pointing out that the leg shaking is annoying to me (and I suspect others).

Suggestions?

Comment: Is the vibration coming to you via the floor or shared cubicle wall, or via your desk?  (I'm wondering what mitigation is possible.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio Seems like floor, though possibly cube wall. I've moved my desk back so that there *should* be no vibration carried between the desks, and my desk also does not touch our common cube wall.

Comment: Note that this may be something not completely controllable, due to a neurological condition. The place to start is certainly to politely ask, as suggested below... but a real answer may wind up having to involve things like padded footrests, and a complete solution may not be possible short of mechanically isolating the workstations.

Comment: [You could try using it to your tactical advantage](http://xkcd.com/228/). Jokes aside, politely pointing it out should be totally acceptable. I tend to shake my leg, and while I try to be alert to whether or not it's disturbing others, I'm not 100% perfect and do appreciate being informed when the case is otherwise.

Comment: You just made me realize I'm shaking my leg right now at home.  =\

Comment: Seriously, how can politely asking him not to do it not be the right answer?

Comment: @DavidRicherby that should be the right answer, but the OP should be prepared for nothing being done, by the coworker. I have genetically carried familial tremors, which appears to a layman as Parkinson's. It is not. My head shakes, my hands shake and my legs shake, I sort of constantly bounce on my toes. There is nothing I can do about it, it is diagnosed and disclosed to my employer. All that being said, there is nothing my company can do without breaking laws. If I am asked, nicely, I would be willing to relocate desks, but that's it, from my perspective.

Comment: @CGCampbell Sure. Ask the guy to stop and if he's unwilling or unable to stop, *then* there's a question to be asked here about what to do next.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Mostly because asking to stop is a temporary fix. It will start again, and there's almost nothing either party can do to prevent it entirely (IMO).

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I recently moved my seat to an area of raised flooring and experienced similar problems.  I politely informed my co-worker of the leg bouncing and he tries to keep it under control.  That's definitely the first step to take.  However, the bouncing is likely somewhat habitual/involuntary.

What I ended up doing is buying a Mario-themed bobble-head doll and putting it up between our desks.  I explained to him that "I have a tendency to tap my foot to music I listen to, and this will hopefully help me notice and keep from bothering you."  That way I was calling attention to it while putting the onus on me rather than him.  Now we both use it to inform us when the bouncing is out of control, and it is a bit of an inside joke:)

Comment: Clever to using a physical/material solution to a social problem. This is the extention of the principle that says: "Why make a rule telling people not to put there hands near the fan blades, when I can put a grill over it."

Comment: This is a realy clever and fun solution , here comes my upvote

Comment: This is a great idea. I'm currently suffering from a neighboring co-worker doing this to me (and he's a bigger guy, so it's literally like I'm driving around at a construction site, bouncing up and down, both of my monitors shaking, me watching the coffee in my cup tremble, as if a T-rex was approaching). Today was payday, so I wonder what kind of bobble head I'll get!! +1 for sure! Thanks.

Comment: What a great idea. It addresses the issue in a pro-social, pro-bonding way, establishing your needs while respecting the other person's needs and autonomy. I don't just like this, I :heart: this.

Answer (score 10):

Your coworker *might* have [restless legs syndrome](http://www.ninds.nih.gov/disorders/restless_legs/detail_restless_legs.htm). Although for many people the leg-shaking is simply an annoying habit or a treatable condition (such as ADHD), for others it may make as much sense to ask them to stop as it does to ask a snorer to stop snoring.

If simply asking him to stop doesn't work, or only works temporarily, or he says he actually has a medical condition, then I would inquire about putting up some ornament or piece of furniture so the sight of it doesn't distract you, and dealing with the noise as you'd deal with any other noise issue in the office (usually headphones, but maybe you can get yourself moved).

Comment: I bounce my legs. It’s not a habit. I have mild RLS. Even when I'm aware of it, I can't always help it.

Comment: I have this habit too due to restless leg.  Not so much a habit per se, as it is a means to an end for ending actual pain.  My legs actually start aching sitting still and bouncing them immediately stops the pain.  I get this same pain when lying on my back in bed, and quickly switching to my side relieves it.  Also get it if I am forced to walk too slowly, due to someone in front of me walking a lot slower than my natural pace.  I'm not being impatient, my legs actually start hurting if I start taking short strides vs. larger comfortable ones (I'm 6'1").

Comment: To add to the above, I am certainly aware of it, and stop immediately when I notice I'm shaking the table, or something.  My wife is the only person who has ever spoke up and told me to stop.  I pretty much have to fold my legs up into the chair with me, stretching the muscles, to relieve the pain, or simply get up and walk around.  Now if only she'd stop chewing chips with her mouth as wide open as one could (yeah, bit one sided on that, I have to stop, but am met with "too bad", "deal with it" from her side under the same conditions).

Answer (score 6):

I used to share a small room with two other coworkers, one of which had this annoying habit of repeatedly shaking his leg up and down (even while not listening to music), to the point where the noise was really irritating and distracting.

**My solution was to simply politely ask my coworker to refrain from doing this**. After I informed him of this, he would stop shaking his leg so much, but still occasionally did it anyways (it must have been habitual, after all). So when it continued, I simply tried to do my best to ignore it (sometimes my work was so interesting and engrossing that this was easy). Other times, when I simply couldn't focus, I would politely point out to my coworker that he was shaking his leg again, at which point he would stop again (at least for a few hours, or the day).

If you work in a larger office, or otherwise have the **option of moving to another location** that's far enough away that you won't be distracted by your coworker, I would consider that an option.

I could see that some people might suggest **escalating the issue to a supervisor** if your coworker won't listen when you inform him that the leg shaking is distracting. It's definitely an option, but it's only one that I would take as a last resort. I would much prefer to just find another location in the office to work, personally.

Answer (score 4):

I have pinched nerves and other damage to my lower back. I generally use a wheelchair. My leg shacking is a result of these injuries. I wish I could control it. I can hold my legs in place with a LOT of effort, but it is VERY painful. In fact, I get charlie horse from the effort and will break out into sweat. People often ask me to stop and even get mad at me when I do not. I have had bobble heads put on my desk, and complaints to HR.

Please understand for some people there is a medical condition that causes it. Trust me the majority of us do not want to be a bother to the rest of you that do not have such issues.

Answer (score 1):

I have restless leg syndrome and I am a habitual leg shaker, although I don't absolutely know the two are connected. I think of RLS more in terms of how I find it hard to sit still in confined paces, or when I'm tired, and it's hard to control. What I do at a desk is in my control, but often starts subconsciously.

Some offices make this effect more obvious than others:

- wooden floors carry it better than concrete
- if we use desks with monitor arms, the monitors are supported less stably and are more likely to amplify vibrations

Some co-workers are more sensitive to it than others. I will always stop at least temporarily when asked, but it's certainly not uncommon for a sensitive co-worker to have to ask a few times over the course of a day. I don't ever do it deliberately around a sensitive co-worker, but ... it's rarely something I consciously start anyway.

Not putting my desk near a sensitive co-worker is probably a good start, if that's possible. Finding ways to have very stable desks with shock absorption would be great, although I haven't seen products that do this well that I'd recommend. I'd be curious to try vibration damping pads under the desk legs. Under my legs too, if they'd work under a task chair.

In essence -- in my experience there hasn't been a great solution. I'd love it if someone were to find one. Asking is certain a totally reasonable and sensible approach, but whether you will be able to get relief on this path without feeling like you have to ask constantly is a question that only you will be able to answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was shaking my leg like i do on occasion at work
and was shaking the table and didnt realise. A co-worker
said hey mate could u stop shaking and i did, no offence taken
at all on several different occasions. So moral is just ask,
even have a laugh about it, dosnt have to be a serious thing.

Comment: This does not add anything to the answers already given.

Comment: This merely repeats points made over a year ago. Please see [Back It Up and Don't Repeat Others](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/255/faq-proposal-back-it-up-and-dont-repeat-others)

Answer (score -1):

As other commenters have suggested, one option is to simply make them aware of it and ask that they stop.  That doesn’t always work though… depending on your relationship it may be complicated to bring it up, or they may be the kind of person who wouldn’t cease shaking out of respect for others alone.

There is another way to make the leg-shaker aware without any sort of confrontation required: subtly make a noise of your own that matches the frequency of their shaking.  Tapping your finger, a pen, etc against the underside of your desk, for example.  Start quietly and increase the intensity until they become aware/annoyed by the noise and stop shaking, at which point you stop the noise.  They will assume they are the cause of the noise, which usually is enough to put a pause to the behavior for a while.