# How to deal with a co-worker that constantly clears his throat?

Tags: coworking

I have a coworker that sits in the office next to me that is constantly clearing his throat... loudly!  I almost think this is more of a nervous habit than an actual medical condition of having gunk in his throat, but I can't be sure.

It's extremely distracting to me and drives me crazy!

Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: Other questions with possibly relevant answers: [Disgusting coworker](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/4027/how-can-i-deal-with-a-disgusting-coworker), [Loud coworker](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/4206/what-can-i-do-about-a-very-loud-coworker), [Coworker's leg-shaking](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/30847/how-to-handle-co-workers-leg-shaking)

Comment: @Vietnhi: I haven't asked anyone else about it.  He's been here about 3 months, so I'm pretty sure it's not a cold.  It's been going on for 3 months.  No, I'm the senior guy here.